# Set default order of Custom Fields inside Layout Tab

Tags: plugin-development, fieldtypes, custom-fieldtype

I'm writing a custom plugin, and I want to specify a custom order of the Fields in a tab. My plugin installs several fields, and I want the user to be able to simply add the tab that contains my fields, and not worry about shuffling the fields into their proper order.

Right now it's ordering my fields alphabetically. Is there a way to specify this?

Any help is greatly appreciated! I *think* it might have something to do with creating a Field Layout Model for my plugin, but I'm not sure.

For reference, I'm talking about specifying a custom order this area:

[image]